# When to navigate from Authentication SwitchNavigator?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm setting up authentication flow in my React Native app, and I can pretty much get everything to work, except I can't figure out the actual proper place to navigate to the logged in stack with `this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");`.

I have a Switch Navigator at the top of my app rendering the auth stack (its own switch nav) and the main stack:

```js
// App.js

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: AuthNavigator,
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  })
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <AppContainer />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The login screen is a complete dummy setup for now (it calls a local api and succeeds no matter what). **Note** the conditional at the start of the render method:

```js
// LoginView.js

class LoginView extends Component {
  state =  { username: "", password: "" };

  handleLogin() {
    this.props.login.call(this);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.user) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Overlay>
          <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <DotIndicator color={"darkgrey"} />
            <Text>Logging in...</Text>
          </View>
        </Overlay>

        // ... input components ...
        <Button
          title="Login"
          onPress={this.handleLogin.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoading: state.auth.isLoading,
    user: state.auth.user,
    error: state.auth.error
  }),
  { login }
)(LoginView);
```

Now, this technically works but I get the error `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`.

I understand this to be thrown because I'm calling the `navigate` inside of the `render`. Makes sense.

I've tried navigating from my login action:

```js
export function login() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    fetch(url) // this will need to be a POST session (not a GET user)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: users[0] });
        console.log("Login succeeded");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn("login failed");
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: error });
      });
  };
}
```

And it works but of course is very wrong in terms of separation of concerns, and this kind of solution also doesn't really stretch as far when I try use it for handling login failure.

I've also thought about doing it in my `handleLogin()` function (called by my login button), with and without async/await:

```js
  async handleLogin() {
    await this.props.login.call(this);
    console.log("Navigating to main screen");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
  }
```

But the navigation happens before the action finishes and the user is logged in, which is of course unacceptable once the auth flow is real. (Plus, when I do it with async/await, "Login Succeeded" gets logged twice! Beats me). It does feel like I'm on the right track doing it in my `handleLogin()` function.

Where do I put my `navigate` call?

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found something that works, but it takes steps away from Redux, and that makes me *slightly* uncomfortable.

I've taken all the fetching out of the Redux action and put it right in my `LoginView`. I'm considering this okay in Redux terms, because the only place the program needs to know about the authorization process and state is in the authorization flow itself (in the `LoginView` itself, for now). The only thing the store and the rest of the app need to know is the info for the user.

So I've replaced my Redux `login` action with a simple `assignUser` action. I've refactored the fetching into `performLogin`, which I call from the old `handleLogin`, after posting a state change to activate my "Logging in..." overlay.

```js
// authActions.js

export function assignUser(user) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("user", user);
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: user });
  };
}

// from LoginView.js

  performLogin() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users") // this will need to be a POST session (not a GET user)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => {
        console.log("Login succeeded");
        this.props.assignUser(users[0]);
        console.log("Navigating to main screen");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn("login failed", error);
        this.setState({isLoading: false})
      });
  }

  handleLogin() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }, this.performLogin);
  }
```

The rest of the `LoginView` component is the same as in my original post.

I'd still love to know if anyone has any methods for accomplishing this that keep the actions fully within Redux.